# Replacing a line in a large number of java source files

Tags: java, eclipse, rad

I have around 600 java classes in a project with random names (there is no pattern in their names).

I want to replace a particular line from inside these classes with another line.

For e.g. line inside these files is

```
System.out.println("Product is: "+myProduct);
```

and I want to replace that line with

```
System.out.println("Object is: "+myObject);
```

The above line is just an example showing what I want to achieve.

I am using RAD 7.5 for development.

Is there a simple way to do this in all 600 files at once?

Comment: Do you have access to a UNIX system?  (or Windows emulator for UNIX.)  If so you, could use a find command and chain it to replace.

Comment: @JeanneBoyarsky: No. No access to UNIX system.

Comment: Then go with JB Nizet proposed.  (I actually forgot Eclipse does that now since I so rarely need a global search/replace on Windows.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. By opening the Search - File... dialog box, entering what you want to search for and the file filter you want, and then clicking *Replace*.

Comment: Making sure you have the project/package selected in the package explorer so it doesn't just do it for one file.

Answer (score 1):

> No. No access to UNIX system.

That's your first problem.  Install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) so you have a solid shell, and then you can learn how to do batch operations on source code.  Being able to `grep` around easily can make it much easier to learn your way around large code-bases and narrow down the amount of code that is likely to contribute to a thorny problem.

Once you've got that installed, you can solve your immediate problem with

```
perl -i.bak \
  -pe 's/System.out.println\("Product is: "+myProduct\);/System.out.println("Object is: "+myObject);/' \
  file0.java file1.java ...
```

Breaking it down:

1. `-i` means treat the arguments as files to modify in-place
2. `.bak` means make a copy of the input files with the `.bak` extension before making changes
3. `-p` means wrap the program in a loop that grabs a line, runs the program, and prints the line
4. `-e 's/.../.../'` means the quoted part is the program to run, and it does a regular expression substitution.
5. the rest are the files to run it on.

Alternatively,

```
find . -name \*.java
```

should list all the java source files under the current directory.

Assuming that directory doesn't have spaces in its path, you can then do

```
find . -name \*.java | xargs perl -i.bak -pe 's/.../.../'
```

where the `...` is the replacement above to run it over all Java sources under the working directory.